# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error in formcontrolname

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a form right know, but I am always getting the error

> 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'

eventhough I tried a few things like writing the `formControlName` in `[]` or trying to get the value over form.controls or get none of these worked, can someone help me out with this? I get the error in my input fields.

TS file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chronos-employee-insurrance',
  templateUrl: './employee-insurrance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-insurrance.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeInsurranceComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public employeeId: number;
  @Input()
  public modalRef: BsModalRef;

  isSaving = false;
  private eventManager: JhiEventManager;




  @Input()
  employeeInsurranceForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private employeeInsuranceService: EmployeeInsurranceService

  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeInsuranceService.findByEmployeeId(this.employeeId).subscribe(res => {

      this.initializeForm(res.body.body);

    });
  }




  initializeForm(insurance: IEmployeeInsurrance) {
    this.employeeInsurranceForm = this.fb.group({
      AFM :       new FormControl(''),
      IKA:       new FormControl(''),
      AMKA:       new FormControl(''),
      SteuerId:   new FormControl(''),
      employeeId: new FormControl(this.employeeId)
    });
    if (insurance) {
      this.employeeInsurranceForm.patchValue(<{ [key: string]: any }>insurance);
    }
  }


  save() {
    this.isSaving = true;
    this.employeeInsuranceService
      .update(this.employeeInsurranceForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<IEmployeeInsurrance>) => this.onEmployeeInsuranceSaveSuccess(res.body),
      );
  }

  private onEmployeeInsuranceSaveSuccess(result: IEmployeeInsurrance) {
    this.eventManager.broadcast({ name: 'employee-insurance-changed', result });
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.closeModal();
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }
```

HTML File:

```
<div class="modal-box">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button
      aria-label="Close"
      class="close"
      type="button"
      (click)="closeModal()"
    >
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{ 'Insurrance information' | translate }}</h4>
  </div>

  <form
    >
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="master">
          <div class="smart-form" [formGroup]="employeeInsurranceForm" (submit)="save()">
            <fieldset>
                  <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="input">
                      <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                      <input
                        class="form-control"
                        name="IKA"
                        formControlName="IKA"
                        placeholder="IKA"
                      />

                    </label>
                  </section>

                  <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="input">
                      <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="AMKA"
                        formControlName="AMKA"
                        placeholder="AMKA"
                      />

                    </label>
                  </section>

                  <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="input">
                      <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="AFM"
                        class="form-control"
                        formControlName="AFM"
                        placeholder="AFM"
                      />

                    </label>
                  </section>

                  <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="input">
                      <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="SteuerID"
                        class="form-control"
                        formControlName="SteuerID"
                        placeholder="Steuer ID"
                      />

                    </label>
                  </section>
            </fieldset>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="closeModal()">
        {{ 'Cancel' | translate }}
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="save()"
      >
        <div [ngClass]="{'editableform-loading' : isSaving }"></div>
        {{ 'Save' | translate }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, what's the point of passing thz form as an input if you assign it to a new memory reference afterwards ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your form is depending on an async HTTP call, simply protect it from errors :

```
<div *ngIf="employeeInsurranceForm" 
  class="smart-form" 
  [formGroup]="employeeInsurranceForm" 
  (submit)="save()">
```

And, as stated in my comment, do not pass your form as in input to your control, since you don't use it at all and assign it on component initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

You could to try to build the form using the FormBuilder in the constructor and then only intialize the data in ngOnInit().